# printing a value of a variable in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fixMissingFiles() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    deletedContactId integer;
    BEGIN
            SELECT INTO deletedContactId contact_id FROM myContacts WHERE id=206351;

            -- print the value of deletedContactId variable to the console

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I print the value of the deletedContactId to the console?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

You can raise a notice in `Postgres` as follows:

```sql
RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', deletedContactId;
```

Read [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) for more details.

Comment: You can also `raise exception 'Value: %', deletedContactId;`, which will raise an actual exception (obviously). This was useful for me because my web app was not logging notice-level messages to my STDOUT. Raising an exception was the quickest way for me to debug something.

Comment: You can also `raise notice 'Value: %  %', deletedContactId, E'\n';`
Which also gives you `newline` after this message.

Comment: use **single commas** and don't commit mistake of double commas like me

Comment: The levels may vary: DEBUG, LOG, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, and EXCEPTION. I can even see LOG in my pgsql's docker log :'-)

Answer (score 3):

Also, the SELECT INTO you're using looks like PostgreSQL for copying rows into a table.  See, for example, [the SELECT INTO doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html) which state: "SELECT INTO -- define a new table from the results of a query"

In pgplSQL I'm used to seeing it in this order: SELECT  INTO  ...  so your first line should probably be:

```
        SELECT contact_id INTO deletedContactId FROM myContacts WHERE id=206351;
```

As described in [Executing a Query with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).