# How to print postgres "raise notice" output from Sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Raise notice is typically used to debug PSQL scripts in postgres ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465429/printing-a-value-of-a-variable-in-postgresql)).

[The docs say that there's some kind of support for printing notices when using the pg gem](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html#label-postgres), but there's no info on how to use this proc, what it yields, possible (probable?) caveats etc.

Does anyone have a working code example for production and/or development? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that allows PG notices to be printed out in development when Sequel logging is enabled.

When I do:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(
  ENV['DATABASE_URL'],
  notice_receiver: lambda{ |x| binding.pry }
)
```

the `notice_receiver` lambda never gets called once I execute a function that raises a notice. I.e

```
[1] pry(#<Psql::CalculateMasterBalancesTest>)> DB.select{ |o| Sequel.function(:emit_notice) }.first
I, [2017-05-17T16:51:56.746003 #23139]  INFO -- : (0.000335s) SELECT emit_notice() LIMIT 1
=> {:emit_notice=>""}
```

where emit notice is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emit_notice()
  RETURNS VOID AS $$

BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'NOTICE ME!!!';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and it works from PgAdmin:

```
NOTICE:  NOTICE ME!!!
Total query runtime: 21 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

**UPDATE**

Alejandro C gave a good working example, and it seems that notices don't get distributed with the `notice_receiver` hook. For example:

```
Sequel.connect(DB.opts.merge(:notice_receiver=>proc{|r| puts r.result_error_message})){ |db|
  db.do("BEGIN\nRAISE NOTICE 'foo';\nEND;")
}
```

prints nothing, and:

```
Sequel.connect(DB.opts.merge(:notice_receiver=>proc{|r| puts r.result_error_message})){ |db|
  db.do("BEGIN\nRAISE WARNING 'foo';\nEND;")
}
```

Prints

> WARNING:  foo

Since [Sequel just calls `set_notice_receiver` from PG](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb#L257), I guess I should file a bug report with PG.

**EDIT 2**

Yet when I try things just with the PG gem I get

```
conn = PG.connect( :dbname => 'db_test', user: 'test', password: 'test', host: '127.0.0.1' )
conn.set_notice_receiver{|r| puts r.result_error_message }
conn.exec("SELECT emit_notice()")
NOTICE:  NOTICE ME!!!
=> #<PG::Result:0x0000000405ac18 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>
```

So at this point I'm a bit confused...

**EDIT 3**

[Posted an issue GitHub...](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/1362)

**EDIT 4**

Ah, apparently there's another options you need to use, `client_min_messages` needs to be set to `:notice` as so:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(
  ENV['DATABASE_URL'],
  notice_receiver: proc{|r| puts r.result_error_message},
  client_min_messages: :notice
)
```

and this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass in your own proc which gets the notice as a string. To have it trigger on notices and not [just warnings and above](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/88180f7b46140687070f81bbf0c9cd7a0436f18d/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/postgres.rb#L52), use client_min_messages. For example:

```
a = nil
Sequel.connect(
  DB.opts.merge(
      notice_receiver: proc{|r| a = r.result_error_message}, 
      client_min_messages: :notice)) { |db|
  db.do("BEGIN\nRAISE WARNING 'foo';\nEND;")
}
a == "WARNING:  foo\n" # true
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I'll play with it. I updated the answer with some stuff I've tried by now

Comment: `DB.inspect` returns `"#<Sequel::Postgres::Database: \"postgres://test:test@127.0.0.1:5432/db_test\" {:notice_receiver=>#<Proc:0x00000003f2e0d8@.../Backend/config/initializers/00_database.rb:4>}>"`, and `require 'pg'`  returns false so I guess it's the right adapter?

Comment: Hmf, I nailed it, it seems notices don't get distributed with the notice_receiver hook, but warnings do. I'll workaround this for now by using `raise warning` where I should be doing `raise notice` and see through the source code what's up.

Comment: Try setting client_min_messages to `:notice` in the spec?

Comment: Want to edit your answer to include the `client_min_messages` angle and I'll accept it?