# Python3 print entire output from 'raise notice' from stored function in Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I'm trying to generate documentation from database from stored functions from postgres with python - all tables and columns contains comments. To do this I found possibility [how to print from function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23466671/1350091) and how to [read the notices from python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275423/1350091).
Unfortunately when I call `conn.notices`, entire code below:

```
import psycopg2  # pip3 install psycopg2

def get_documentation_generated_by_db(user, password, db):
    notices = ''
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host="localhost",
            database=db,
            user=user,
            password=password)

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT printAllTablesNamesAndDescriptionInMarkdown();")
        notices = conn.notices
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    return notices
```

**The output is truncated.**

The code of stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printAllTablesNamesAndDescriptionInMarkdown() RETURNS void as $$
DECLARE
  table_name varchar;
  table_description varchar;
BEGIN
  raise notice '| table | description |';
  raise notice '| ----- | ----------- |';

  for table_name, table_description in select tablename, obj_description(('public.'||tablename)::regclass) from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname = 'public'
  loop
    raise notice '| **%** | % |', table_name, table_description;
  end loop;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Probably the solution would be to call `psql` from the script, but rather it is dirty solution.

---

**So the question is: how to get entire text of notices from postgres' function?** I can use different library from python if necessarily.

BTW. The question is not duplicated with [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274199/python2-print-postgresql-stored-procedure-raise-notice).

Comment: Per docs [Connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html) `notices`: "To avoid a leak in case excessive notices are generated, only the last 50 messages are kept. ...". So are you dealing with more the 48 tables? You would be better off returning a [Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) section *43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY*

Comment: If you insist on staying with `NOTICE` then build a string in the loop and `RAISE NOTICE` on the entire string instead of doing `RAISE NOTICE` for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres notifications are not intended for transferring regular data. Get the data you need by running SQL query and format results in your application, e.g .:

```
    query = """
        select tablename, obj_description(('public.'||tablename)::regclass)
        from pg_catalog.pg_tables 
        where schemaname = 'public'
    """
    print("| table | description |");
    print("| ----- | ----------- |");
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            print(f"| **{row[0]}** | {row[1]} |")
```

Comment: Note that this is not just an alternative. This is the right way to do what you want. Trying to use notifications for this, you choose winding forest paths for your luxury car instead of taking the comfortable highway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
def generate_documentation_from_db(db_name: str, user: str, passwd: str, host: str='localhost'):
    command = f'PGPASSWORD={passwd} psql -h {host} -d {db_name} -U {user} --quiet  ' \
              f'-c "SELECT public.generatedbdocumentation();" 2>&1 | sed -r "s/^NOTICE:  //"'
    return run_command(command)
    

def run_command(command: str):
    command_result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    command_result.wait()
    if command_result.returncode == 0:
        return command_result.stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
    else:
        print('!Command executing error!:', command,
              'Reason:', command_result.stderr.read().decode("utf-8").strip())
        sys.exit(command_result.returncode)
```